# Continuity in $\mathbb{R^2}$ notation

Tags: continuity

If $u(\xi=0+, \eta)=u(\xi=0-,\eta)$

Does this mean

$\lim \limits_{\xi \to 0+}u(\xi,\eta)=\lim \limits_{\xi \to 0-}u(\xi,\eta)$ ?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that would be the meaning, if I should take a guess - especially if it makes sense in whatever context you've seen it in.

Comment: I'm not sure if it does make sense. The next line states: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}(0+,\eta$)=$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}(0-,\eta$). We have assumed $u$ is continuous at $(0,\eta)$.

Comment: That next line looks like you have also assumed that the partial derivative wrt. $\eta$ is continuous at $(0,\eta)$. Is this so?

Comment: The only extra information I have is that $u$ is smooth for $\xi \neq 0$. Does this not mean that the partial derivatives exist everywhere except $\xi=0$?

Comment: @usainlightning yes, it does. So I don't know why your source writes up the definition of continuity at $(0,\eta)$, but there's probably a reason given in the context.